# Promises in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

Aiming to get image urls for users found in a message history.
Obviously after I loop through `data.directMessages.map` object image url values never make it to `res.render('index', {data})`
I'm convinced I need `data.directMessages.map` to perform all operations first and ONLY then have the result returned. Could you help me
to figure out how?

It's my pseudo code:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   Promise.all(arrayOfPromises).
   then(data => {
       return {
           ...
           ...
           directMessages: ...
       }
   }).
   // HELP NEEDED HERE !!!
   then(data => {
       data.directMessages.map(info => {
           const getData = await getProfileDataById(info);
            info.profile_img_url = await getData.profile_img_url;
           });
           return data;
       // HELP END !!!
       }).then(data => {
           res.render('index', {data});
       })
    })
```

I'm thinking of doing this

```
const results = data.DirectMessages.map(async (info)=> {
    // do stuff and return results
});
Promise.all(results).then(data => data);
```

Would it be the right way to solve it?

Comment: `map(async info =>`? `await` outside an `async` function is Bad, I believe.

Comment: Also, don't forget that `map` returns the modified array and **it doesn't modify it in place**. If you want to modify `data` with a `map` function, just do it as follows `data.directMessages = data.directMessages.map(...`.

Comment: `const getData = await getProfileDataById(id);` is `id` is part of `data.directMessages` ? or will it be same for all `data.directMessages`?

Comment: @karthik Oh, yes. I should have replaced id with info.

Comment: i also want to check if  `getProfileDataById(info)` & `getData.profile_img_url` returns promises

Comment: @karthik 
The issue I have is that I need loop through data.directMessage, create new objects, them values from getData object which I get through another promise and finally return results.
In steps
1) loop through an array ob object, perform operations
2) return results
3) use results in the next promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `async/await` as following way(assuming that `getProfileDataById(info)` will return promise)

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    let data = await Promise.all(arrayOfPromises);
    data = {
        ...
        ...
        directMessages: ...
    };
    // Promise.all help you run parallel execution  
    const getData = await Promise.all(data.directMessages.map(info => getProfileDataById(info)));
    getData.forEach((profileData, i) => {
        data.directMessages[i].profile_img_url = profileData.profile_img_url;
    })
    res.render('index', {
        data
    });
})
```

Comment: Awesome! That's the logic I was looking for all this time!!! Couldn't figure out that await is only used before promises. It's getting more clear now.